# How to iterate through two lists with iter() and yield?

Tags: python, python-3.x, loops, iterable

A simple example:

```
 popen = subprocess.Popen(cmd, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE, universal_newlines=True, shell=True)
 for stdout_line in iter(popen.stdout.readline, ""): # how to add popen.stderr.readline check?
     yield stdout_line
```

We read from `popen.stdout`, yet we also want to read from `stderr` at the same time! We do not know when process will end.

So How to iterate through two lists with iter() and yield?

Comment: You'll probably need to use read() on the streams and do your own buffering and EOF detection.

Comment: umm...you want to **read** std**out**?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

These aren't lists, and the right way to work with them isn't how you would work with lists. If you want to stuff a process's stdout and stderr into one combined stream, do that with output redirection:

```
from subprocess import PIPE, STDOUT

process = subprocess.Popen(cmd, stdout=PIPE, stderr=STDOUT, ...)
#                                                   ^^^^^^
```

Comment: It will work in my particular example here, yet is there a generalisation?

Comment: @DuckQueen: Depends on what you want to generalize it to (and before you ask, generalizing it to lists doesn't make sense). I suggest doing some background reading on lists and streams first, and then posting a new question if you still have something to ask by the end of that.